# How to convert text into graphic without lose of quality

Tags: flash, actionscript

```
        ex = new TextField();
        ex.styleSheet = styleSheet; //some custom fonts
        ex.htmlText = '<p>EX</p>';
        ex.autoSize = 'left';
        //ex.embedFonts = true;
        //var exbitmap:Bitmap;
        //exbitmap = new Bitmap( new BitmapData(ex.width,ex.height,true,0x000000));
        //exbitmap.bitmapData.draw(ex);
        var bitmapdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(ex.width, ex.height, true, 0x00000000);
        bitmapdata.draw(ex);


        graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapdata);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, ex.width, ex.height);
        graphics.endFill();
```

the problem is that when i draw text as graphic, it loses quality, how to do that witout loosing quality?

[image]

[image]

see the differenece?

this first is converted to image, and the second is the original

Comment: Try to change antialiasing `ex.antiAliasType=AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`

Comment: Do you have screenshots of what it looks like as text and as bitmap?  That might make it easier to tell what the problem is.

Comment: i've tried to use the ex.antiAliasType=AntiAliasType.ADVANCED, maybe there are other options to fix this? any ideas?

Comment: @RustamKichinsky Try to set `embedFonts` to `true`, and then apply `ADVANCED` antialiasing. Also [sharpness](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#sharpness) property could be usefull for you.

Comment: oo thanks, i will try these....

Comment: so i've settet embedFonts = true, antialias.ADVANCED, and also sharpness = 400, the result is close to the original, but still  
fuzzily... anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the text field's coordinates are integers.

```
ex.x = int(/*your formula*/);
//or
ex.x = Math.round(/*your formula*/);
```